# For MVVM, what is the best practice for viewmodel to export the property in model to view?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, viewmodel

As a new one to WPF, I start my MVVM travel recently. I can understand the orginal intension about why we need MVVM, but some of the implementation detail still confuse me a lot.

Here is one of my questions:

**How should I export the property in `model` to `View` via `ViewModel`**

I can show some of my idea here, so please share your view with me.

Here is one of my implementation:

```cs
    class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private String _name;
        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set 
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    class MyViewModel
    {
        private MyModel _model;

        public MyModel Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }
    }
```

I think the problem for this is we do not decouple the view from model. And the view need to know every detail about the model implementation to accomplish the Binding process. And exporting the propert in `Model` **directly** to view from `ViewModel` cannot be treat as a good design in my opinion.

So I hope you can share your experience on the design about this topic.

BTW,
If we export many object, such as, a `List` of `MyModel` object to view from viewmodel, how can I implement this to decouple the view from model?

Comment: The view does not need to know every detail about the model implementation, the view only needs to know the names of the property to bind to. In your case, this would be the Name property. If you had some method to format this name, retrieve this name from the database, etc. This would be in your Model/ViewModel class and the view would not need to know any of that at all => decoupled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not your Model, but your ViewModel shall implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Then you can use Binding in the View to get the Data from the ViewModel.

In your View / XAML you have statements like

```
... Content="{Binding myViewModelProperty}" ...
```

depending on what you are binding.

myViewModelProperty has to be a public property in your ViewModel

```
public string myViewModelProperty { get; set; }
```

Do not forget to call RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged (or what your handler is called) in the setter to get updates in the View.

```
private string myViewModelField;

public string myViewModelProperty 
{ 
   get
   {
        return myViewModelField;
   }
   set
   {
       myViewModelField = value;
       RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(() => myViewModelProperty);
   }
}
```

** Update **

Lists are typically "exported" via `ObservableCollection<Type>`.
Ideally `Type` is some ViewModel here, created with data from the model to
be shown in your View. You can imagine the ViewModel as `Adapter` between
your model and your view.

Comment: If I create the ViewModel like this, does it mean I need to write code to map every Model property to ViewModel proerpty? Is it too complicated?

Comment: This should be trivial. Sometimes I add a factory method like `public SomeViewModel FromModel(SomeModel model)` that does this mapping in a few lines. The important part is that you adapt your model data for the view and you have a clean separation of concerns in case of updates of the model.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a strict rule, but in my case I prefer to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModels and to leave the Models as simple POCOs.

It can be annoying to "repeat" the properties of the Model in the ViewModel, but :

1. Generally you don't need to expose all the properties to the View.
2. It allows you to add additional code like user input validation in your VM and keep your Model "clean".

So in your example it would be:

```
   class MyModel
    {
        public String Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }     
    }

    class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase //let's say you have this base class in your framework
    {
        private MyModel model;

        public MyViewModel(MyModel model)
        {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public string Name 
        {
            get
            {
                 return this.model.Name;
            }

            set
            {
                 if(IsValidInput(value)
                 {
                     this.model.Name = value;
                     this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); // the ViewModelBase  base class provide this helper.
                 }
            }       
        }    
    }
```

About your second question, [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) is usually a nice way to expose a collection of Models to the view:

```
class ContactListViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Contacts { get; private set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bind your property on view wiuth Model.Name